Why does a Flask-SQLAlchemy query fail when using a named parameter?
I am populating a dropdown with a list of client IDs and names (for an EHR).
In the get_client route the user selects a client and the client_id, the fk, is passed to the progress_view route which queries for an array of progress notes which are handed off to the progress_view.html template.
The template's scrolling div is empty - no stderr but no data. I've tried passing named parameters, session['client_id'] values and request.args.get('client_id'). To troubleshoot I passed the client_id to the template as a scalar along with the array:
return render_template('progress_view.html', notes=results, client_id=client_id).
No matter how I pass the param it shows up atop the template so it is being parsed. (?) Next, I tried using different syntax with SQLAlchemy, same result - no data. So I created a progress_test route when the the client_id is hard coded. This populates the template's scrolling div as well as printing the client_id. I am at a loss as to how to proceed.
Here are my routes:
def get_client():

    clients = db.session.query(MPI).filter().all()

    if request.method == "POST":
        client_id = request.form.get("client_id")

        if client_id:
            session['client_id'] = client_id
            # return render_template('progress_view.html', client_id=client_id)
            return redirect(url_for("chart.progress_view"))

    return render_template('get_client.html', clients=clients)

# @chart.route('/progress_view/<client_id>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@chart.route('/progress_view', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def progress_view():


    # client_id = request.args.get('client_id')
    client_id = session['client_id']
    client_id = int(client_id)

    # from sqlalchemy import select
    # sth = select(ProgressNote.unitname, ProgressNote.staffname, ProgressNote.notedate, ProgressNote.notebody).where(ProgressNote.client_id == client_id)
    # results = db.session.execute(sth)

    results = db.session.query(ProgressNote).filter(ProgressNote.client_id == client_id).all()

    return render_template('progress_view.html', notes=results, client_id=client_id)

@chart.route('/progress_test', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def progress_test():

    client_id = 3
    from sqlalchemy import select
    sth = select(ProgressNote.unitname, ProgressNote.staffname, ProgressNote.notedate, ProgressNote.notebody).where(ProgressNote.client_id == client_id)
    results = db.session.execute(sth)

    return render_template('progress_view.html', notes=results, client_id=client_id)

The template:
  <div id="logview">
  <table style="border: 0px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; width:999px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <tbody>
  {% for note in notes %}
  <tr style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;" >
  <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;"><b>Unit Name:</b>  <br />{{ note.unitname }}</td>
  <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;"><b>Entered By:</b> <br />{{ note.staffname }}</td>
  <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;"><b>Note Date:</b>  <br />{{ note.notedate }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;" >
  <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left; border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;"><pre>{{ note.notebody}}</pre></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="border: 0px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;" >
  <td colspan="5" style="border-collapse: collapse;">&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>

And the model:
class ProgressNote(UserMixin, db.Model):
        rec_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        client_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
        chart = db.Column(db.String(80))
        unitname = db.Column(db.String(255))
        staffname = db.Column(db.String(255))
        notedate = db.Column(db.DateTime)
        notebody = db.Column(db.String)


In my Perl CGI scripts I use subroutines to post a menu, then a form, then do a query. So it occurred to me: do I really need two routes? No, this works:
@chart.route('/progress_view', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def progress_view():

    clients = db.session.query(MPI).filter().all()

    if request.method == "POST":
        client_id = request.form.get("client_id")

        if client_id:
            results = db.session.query(ProgressNote).filter(ProgressNote.client_id == client_id).all()
            return render_template('progress_view.html', notes=results, client_id=client_id)

    return render_template('get_client.html', clients=clients)

